# Rescue_from routing error solution for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, exception, rescue

In my rails 4 application, I am using the below explained code as rescue_from routing error solution.

In applicationController:-

```
def catch_404
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
  end
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :error_render_method

def error_render_method
  puts "HANDLING ERROR"
  render :file => 'public/404'

end
```

and In routes.rb

```
match "*path", to: "application#catch_404", via: :all
```

For www.abcd.com/wrongroute it works fine, but when I am entering www.abcd.com/account/wrongroute  it shows an error "Unknown action-The action 'show' could not be found".Is it due to the code given in routes.rb? How can i solve this?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: hey, why neither you look at answers to your previous questions nor you answer to comments? some of them are exactly the answer to such question as this one

Comment: Sorry, I have checked those answers, but I didn't get a solution for my problem . Now I solved this, I just restricted the action show from all resources(resources :entities, :except => :show).